# How to express that a pair in a set satisfies a condition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, quantifiers

Simple question, but how would I express that for any ordered pair $n$ in set $M$, $n$ is "special" if its pair adds up to $4$? E.g. $(0,4), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)$. Would this example be appropriate?

$M = \text{a set of ordered pairs}$

$f(n) : n\text{ is special}$

$$\exists n \in M, n_{x} + n_{y} = 4 \Rightarrow f(n)$$

Comment: Do you mean a pair is special if and only if it adds up to $4$? i.e. do there exist special pairs that do not add up to $4$?

Comment: Indeed. Only if its coordinates add up to 4.

Comment: In that case you'll want an equivalence between the statements in you predicate

Comment: So the rightarrow should be changed to a biconditional? I'm also not quite sure if $n_{x}$ represents the value of the x component.

Comment: Yes, exactly. For it all to make sense, firstly define what the elements of $M$ are - I suppose pairs of natural numbers. Then define some notation for the components of a pair and the you're good to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost: Let $M$ be a set of ordered pairs of natural numbers i.e. $M \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. Then define for any $n = (n_x, n_y) \in M:$

$$f(n) :\Leftrightarrow n ~ \text{is special} ~.$$

Then we have

$$ \forall n \in M: f(n) \Leftrightarrow n_x + n_y = 4$$

Note the logical equivalence $\Leftrightarrow$ in the last line.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. So a universal quantifier is better than using an existential quantifier in this case, because the condition applies to all elements?

Comment: @Pandazoic Yes. Not only better, but not false. For any element in $M$, it is special precisely when it adds up to $4$. If you used an existential quantifier, the you only require that for some element in $M$ this is true, which, I am sure, is not what you want

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much for the help.